# What is the difference between Rectification Efficiency and Transformer Utilization Factor?

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier, efficiency

As I was studying half-wave rectifiers and why they are less efficient than center-tapped and bridge type full wave rectifiers, I came across these two terms that both try and describe how well the rectifier... well, rectifies.

Rectification Efficiency = DC power delivered at load ÷ AC input power from transformer secondary
(=40.6% for half wave rectifier)
&

Transformer Utilization Factor = DC power delivered at load ÷ AC power *rating* of the secondary transformer
(=0.287 for half wave rectifier)

Naturally, I tried to find the difference between AC rated power and AC input power but found that my textbook uses them interchangeably.

I've understood the formulae and expressions but would like

1. A **qualitative** differentiation between the two.
2. My book cites: "In any power supply design, TUF is necessary to determine the rating of
   the transformer"

So shouldn't different rectifier circuits(half wave, full wave, etc) differ in *rectification efficiency* alone?
If transformer utilization depends on the characteristics of the primary and secondary windings, why does it depend on the subsequent diode arrangement at all? Why are their values different from model to model? Why is it studied under rectification?